# How can I retrieve the location of a cell (e.g A1)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to build a formula to select a different set of data dependent on what is selected in a drop-down menu list, for example: if I select option 1, I want to retrieve data list 1 which starts at A1, but if I select option 2, I want to retrieve data list 2 which starts at G1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace B1 with the location of your drop-down menu:

```
=transpose(split(arrayformula(ifs(B1=1, concatenate(A:A&","), B1=2, concatenate(G:G&","))), ","))
```

Next time, show the research and work you have done so far.

Comment: oh, sorry about that, i will make sure to include my work next time

Comment: I managed to get it to work, took me a bit to figure out how the formula worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

all you need is simple `IF` statement like:

```
=IF(B1="option 1", {A1:A}, 
 IF(B1="option 2", {G1:G}, ))
```